# Connection between Pseudo random generators and hardness

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, cryptography, lower-bounds, pseudo-random-generators

For a boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ $H_{avg}(f)$ is defined as the largest $S(n)$ s.t. for all circuit $C_n$ of size $S(n)$, $\Pr_{x\in U_n}[C_n(x)=f(x)]<1/2+1/S(n)$. Here $U_n$ is uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^n$.

According to Nisan Wigderson 1988, I know that if there exists $f\in E$ with $H_{avg}(f)\geq S(n)$ then there is a $S'(l)$-Prg where $S'(l)=S(n)^{0.01}$. For any general $S(l)$, a Pseudo-random generator, is called an $(S(l),\epsilon)$-Prg if for circuit family $C_{S(l)}$ of size $S(l)$ $|Pr_{x\in U_{l}}[C_{S(l)}(G(x))=1]-Pr_{x\in U_{S(l)}}[C_{S(l)}(x)=1]|<\epsilon$. Here $G$ is a pseudo random function $G:\{0,1\}^l\longrightarrow\{0,1\}^{S(l)}$, generates an $S(l)$ length strings from length $l$.

I was thinking if the converse is also true or not. Means, if we can show the existence of $S(l)$-Prg, then does it follows that there is $f$ with $H_{avg}(f)\geq S(n)$?

Comment: What is $S'(l)Prg$? Which theorem or lemma in [Nisan Wigderson 1988] implies "if there exists $f\in E$ with $H_{avg}(f)\ge S(n)$ then there is a $S'(l)Prg$ where $S'(l)=S(n)^{0.01}$"?

Comment: " For any general $S(l)$, a Pseudo-random generator, is called an $S(l)-Prg$ if for circuit family $C_n$ of size $S(l)$ $|Pr_{x\in G}[C_n(x)=1]-Pr_{x\in U_n}[C_n(x)=1]|<\epsilon$. Here $G$ is a pseudo random function $G:\{0,1\}^l\longrightarrow\{0,1\}^{S(l)}$, generates an $S(l)$ length strings from length $l$." - This is what I know about $S(l)-prg$. There was a result like this in NIsan Wigderson 1988, but what I asked over here is independent of that. It comes from the definitions and some probability trick, I think..

Comment: You seem to refer to Theorem 1 in [Nisan Wigderson 1988], but the original theorem does not mention 0.01. Where is the 0.01 comes from?

Comment: And Theorem 1 in [Nisan Wigderson 1988] states that the two parts are **equivalent**. Is  that what you want?

Comment: I cannot give you the details of the paper, I am sorry, as I did not go through it. All this I got from my university lecture materials. I just want to know if $\exists\;f$, s.t.  $S(l)-prg->H_{avg}(f)\geq S((n)$. Definitions are all according to above, might be confusing, that is why I am also struggling with it. What I think is it does not have any connection with NW 1988.

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: $\epsilon\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: But what is $\epsilon$? Is it a constant, a negligible function of $n$, or a parameter of the definition (i.e., you mean $(S(l),\epsilon)$-Prg rather than $S(l)$-Prg)? In addition, what do you mean by $x\in G$? Do you mean $\mathrm{Pr}_{x\in U_{S^{-1}(n)}}[C_n(G(x))=1]$? You use both $n$ and $l$ in the definition of $S(l)$-Prg, what is the relation between $n$ and $l$?

Comment: Yes, by $S(l)-prg$, I mean $(S(l),\epsilon)-prg$. Yes, you are right about $G$. I have updated the question to remove $n$ from definition. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 1 in [Nisan Wigderson 1988] implies:

For any function $l\le s(l)\le 2^l$, the following are equivalent:

1. For some $c>0$, there exists a quick PRG $G: l\to s(l^c)$.
2. For some $c>0$, there exists a function $f$ in EXPTIME with hardness $s(l^c)$.

Although their definition of (quick) PRG and hardness are slightly different from yours, I think the conclusion is still the same (as long as $\epsilon <1/2$, and your conclusion should be $H_{avg}(f)\ge S(l^c)$ for some $c$ rather than $H_{avg}(f)\ge S(n)$).

The proof can be summarized as follows:

1. Regard the PRG as an extender from string of length $l$ to string of length $l+1$, and consider the boolean function $f$ corresponding to this extender.
2. Show that $f$ cannot be approximated by circuits of size $S(l^c)$, i.e., for some constant $k$, all large enough $l$, and all circuits $C_l$ of size $S(l^c)$, $\mathrm{Pr}_{x\in U_l}[C_l(x)\neq f(x)]>n^{-k}$ (note this is a weaker condition compared to the definition of hardness, i.e. your $H_{avg}$).
3. Use Yao's lemma [Yao 1982] to xor multiple copies of $f$ to obtain a function $f'$ such that $H_{avg}(f')\ge S(l^c)$.

You can see more details in [Nisan Wigderson 1988].